# botframework - Not able to publish bot on Azure

Tags: azure, botframework

I have a .NET bot which is working perfectly fine on my local, but when I try to host it on Azure I get error message as

> The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

I have tried updating the Load user details to machine settings as per this blog. 
[Configuring machine key protection of session tokens in WIF and Thinktecture IdentityModel](https://brockallen.com/2013/02/18/configuring-machine-key-protection-of-session-tokens-in-wif-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/)

Didn't quite help.
Can someone guide me with this issue?

Comment: What are you trying to deploy to? App Service, IIS, etc?

Comment: Is the site accessible when you navigate to https://sitename.azurewebsites.net/api/messages ?